# re applying animations to existing CAShapelayer

Tags: ios, swift, core-animation, cashapelayer

The following code is used to draw an animated chart based on saved data. The charts path morphs from its initial line to the databased shape. It all works as a charm.

However when i input new data from another view controller and segue back 
i want to reanimate the morphing (now from the previous final shape to the new one). the data gets loaded and the final shape is as it should. Hovewever the path and gradient animation never animates. Its simply instantainously at its final positions.

The transaction completion block do run so i can't seem to figure out what the issue is.

Thanks a bunch!

```
  func fromToAnimPath(fromPath:CGMutablePath,toPath:CGMutablePath)->CAShapeLayer{

    var graphShape:CAShapeLayer!
    if statisticHolderView.layer.sublayers?.count == 2{
        if let oldShape = statisticHolderView.layer.sublayers?.last{
            print("reusing ols cashapelayer from statistichlderview")
            graphShape = oldShape as! CAShapeLayer

        }

    }else{

        print("creating layer for the first time")
        graphShape = CAShapeLayer()
        graphShape.fillColor = nil
        graphShape.strokeColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1).cgColor
        graphShape.lineWidth = 2
        graphShape.path = fromPath
    }
    let gradiantAnim = CABasicAnimation.init(keyPath: "locations")
    gradiantAnim.fromValue = [1,1,1]
    gradiantAnim.toValue = [0.0,0.2,1]
    gradiantAnim.duration = 0.5
    gradiantAnim.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction.init(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut)

    let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    var gradiant:CAGradientLayer!

    if  ((graphShape.sublayers?.count) != nil) {

        if let oldMask = graphShape.sublayers?.first{
            gradiant = oldMask as! CAGradientLayer
            print("Reusing gradiant")
        }
    }else{
        gradiant = CAGradientLayer()
        gradiant.startPoint = CGPoint.init(x: 0, y: 1)
        gradiant.endPoint = CGPoint.init(x: 0, y: 0)
        gradiant.colors = [#colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 0).cgColor,#colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 0).cgColor,#colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 0.9).cgColor]
        gradiant.locations=[0,0.2,1]
        gradiant.backgroundColor = nil
        gradiant.opacity = 0
    }

    maskLayer.frame = toPath.boundingBox
    maskLayer.path = toPath
    gradiant.frame = maskLayer.bounds
    gradiant.mask = maskLayer

    CATransaction.begin()
    CATransaction.setCompletionBlock {
        gradiant.opacity = 1
        gradiant.add(gradiantAnim, forKey: nil)

    }

    let graphAnim = CABasicAnimation.init(keyPath: "path")
    graphAnim.fromValue = graphShape.path
    graphShape.path = toPath
    graphAnim.toValue = graphShape.path
    graphAnim.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction.init(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut)
    graphAnim.duration = 2.7

    graphShape.add(graphAnim, forKey: nil)

    if !didDrawInitialStartGraph{
        print("inserted the graiant as a sublayer")
        graphShape.insertSublayer(gradiant, at: 0)
    }

    CATransaction.commit()

    pathCurve.addPath(toPath)
    didDrawInitialStartGraph = true

    return graphShape
}
```

Comment: Further examining and it might be that the CaAnimation never gets added at all the second time as the completion block will run instantaneously regardless of animation duration.